# @for iteration over a sorted map's keySet() doesn't honour order

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm programming my models, controllers etc in Java.

I have a data model that contains a `SortedMap<String, Foo>`.  The map implementation class is a `TreeMap`.

If, in the template, I render the values of the map (using its `toString()`) like this:

```
@theSortedMap.keySet()
```

... then the values are printed out in the expected, *ascending* order.

However, if I use a `@for` construct:

```
@for(keyValue <- theSortedMap.keySet()) {
  @keyValue <br>
}
```

... then the iteration order becomes unpredictable.

How can I iterate over the map's keys so that the desired iteration order is maintained?

(Is this expected? Or is this a bug in Play?)

Comment: have you tried iterating over the entrySet as well?

Comment: As @radai suggested, try using entrySet(..). If not, can't you use the traditional java for-loop? (I have no experience with Play)

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi: the question's about a play template, so, no. :-)

Comment: @radai: `@for((counterparty, rows) <- pageModel.dataByCounterparty) {` provides a consistent order ... so I can now work around it (thanks!).  That said, I still think the `keySet()` version not working looks like a bug.

Comment: @GregKopff - im far brom being a play expert. open a bug for them ,see what they tell you.

Comment: @radai: yeah, filing a bug is my next port of call -- just thought I'd put out a feeler to see if I was doing something the wrong way.

Comment: Can you wrap the set in a TreeSet?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I'm sure I could.  Using the entry set tuple provides me a workaround to my problem - I'm really looking to see if this is a bug or just the wrong approach.  Looks to be a bug at the moment.

Comment: Open up the source and see if it accidentally gets stuffed in a hash set.  Sounds like time for a bug report

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I wouldn't know where to look in the play source code I'm afraid ...  Decompiling the generated class file for my page didn't reveal anything to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how java collections are transformed into scala collections via implicit conversions. It seems that Maps are only converted to plain scala Maps no matter whether they are sorted or not.

One way of circumventing this is to use this construct to iterate over the set's iterator:

```
@theSortedMap.keySet.iterator.map { key => <li>@key</li>}
```

Comment: How do you account for the fact that if I iterate over the `(key, value)` using `@for((key, value) <- theSortedMap) {` it iterates in the correct, _sorted_ order?

Comment: again, calling the iterator explicitly should work just fine:   `@for((key, value) <- theSortedMap.iterator) {`

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. Your suspicion that any map is converted to a plain scala Map doesn't seem to align with with I see - namely that `@for((k, v) <- map)` honours the order, while `@for(k <- map.keySet())` doesn't. If it were as you said, I wouldn't expect _either_ version to honour the order.

Comment: The code above works and answers the issue of how to do it - but your answer makes assertions about how play converts Java maps to Scala maps that I think either needs to be backed up, or removed for this answer to be correct.

Comment: [This Line](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.2/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala#L27) enables the [implicit conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$) from java to scala types. That `Maps` are dealt with differently might have to do with [this code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/utils/Conversions.scala)

Comment: Thanks for the links. So does the Java -> Scala type conversion only happens at the end? To me that would explain why `@map.keySet.iterator.map` works, but `@for(key <- map.keySet)` doesn't. (It also seems to me that in my example, the problem is the `Set` conversion rather than a `Map` conversion.)  Would you agree?

Comment: `map` and the `@for` idiom is not offered on either Java Object, so this is when scala applies the implicit conversions to find a type that has a `map` associated to it.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. Solved it like this

```
@for((key, value) <- map) {
    <span>@key</span><span>@value</span>
}
```